# Azure - Cannot create SQL database

Tags: sql, azure, cloud

Every time I try and create a new database and a new server in Azure, I am greeted by this cloud icon [image]

Then when I press `ok` in the Add data connection tab, I am prompted by this error:

```
There was an error while creating data connection 'Storage data connection - ma7b51a363647f41'.
```

I have seen the other SO posts about this error, but none of the solutions such as

- Delete all your other database connections and services
- Retry the process

work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same problem. I try same things and still error appears. I find another solution in my problem, I created new Mobile Apps Quickstart and then i created new DB and data connection successfully. I hope this will help you little bit if you are struggling with app services too.